# Django lxml parsing issue with value

Tags: python, django, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an element `submission_ref` with text content `123` that I'm parsing like this:

```
    xml = request.POST['xml'].encode('utf-8')
    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True, encoding='utf-8')
    h = fromstring(xml, parser=parser)

    submission_ref = h.xpath('submission_ref/text()');
```

My issue is that I cannot use the value in the variable `submission_ref` because it looks like this: `['123']` after being parsed. See the extra `['` and `']`.

Has this something to do with `xpath()`? How can I solve this?

Comment: Please, don't use semicolons in Python, they are not needed.

Comment: force of habbat. oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xpath()` function returns a *list* of matches. Simply use the first:

```
submission_ref = h.xpath('submission_ref/text()')[0]
```

Comment: o right!!! I did not know that. So I could do for item in submission_ref also here?